# Optimize a search in 3D

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I asked this first on stackoverflow and someone told me it was more appropriate to ask here, so I've copied it over. I had some trouble trying to decide the best way to phrase this question so I apologize if it's a duplicate and I just missed it.

> I'm trying to optimize code meant to test if a collection of points
>   are arranged in a rectangular prism.  One of the only things I know
>   going in is the first point and that object is aligned with the XYZ
>   grid.  IE a point must lay exactly +X or -X from the first point.

This is what I've come up with:

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public struct possition {
            public float X,Y,Z;
            public void assign(float a,float b, float c){
                this.X = a;
                this.Y = b;
                this.Z = c;
            }
            public void assign(possition that){
                this.X = that.X;
                this.Y = that.Y;
                this.Z = that.Z;
            }
            public possition (possition that){
                this.X = that.X;
                this.Y = that.Y;
                this.Z = that.Z;
            }
            public possition (float a,float b, float c){
                this.X = a;
                this.Y = b;
                this.Z = c; 
            }
            public static bool operator ==(possition Pos1, possition Pos2){
                if (Pos1.X == Pos2.X && Pos1.Y == Pos2.Y && Pos1.Z == Pos2.Z){
                        return true;
                }
                else {return false;}
            }
            public static bool operator !=(possition Pos1, possition Pos2){
                if (Pos1.X != Pos2.X && Pos1.Y != Pos2.Y && Pos1.Z != Pos2.Z){
                        return true;
                }
                else {return false;}
            }
        }
        public struct box {
            public possition boundMin;
            public possition boundMax;
            public bool NotNull;

            public box (possition Min, possition Max, bool NULL){
                this.boundMin = Min;
                this.boundMax = Max;
                this.NotNull = NULL;
            }
        }
        public static bool Occupied(possition checkPos){//this is function here entirelly for testing and demonstration Occupied is an outside function that is unimportant to the question
            possition Fake1 = new possition(0.0f,0.0f,10.0f);
            possition Fake2 = new possition(0.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
            possition Fake3 = new possition(10.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            possition Fake4 = new possition(10.0f,0.0f,10.0f);
            possition Fake5 = new possition(0.0f,10.0f,10.0f);
            possition Fake6 = new possition(10.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
            possition Fake7 = new possition(10.0f,10.0f,10.0f);

            if (checkPos == Fake1 || checkPos == Fake2 || checkPos == Fake3 || checkPos == Fake4 || checkPos == Fake5 || checkPos == Fake6 || checkPos == Fake7) {
                return true;
            }
            else {return false;}
        }
        public static box getBoundingBox(possition cornerOrigin){   
                    cornerOrigin.assign(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f); //this won't always be set to the origin of the cordinate grid, but it's easier for this example to define it as a constant
                    possition scanTarget = new possition(cornerOrigin); //just a holder variable for working with the data in cornerOrigin.
                    possition xy = new possition();
                    possition yz = new possition();
                    possition xz = new possition();
                    possition xyz = new possition();

                    float y=0.0f,x=0.0f,z=0.0f, xMax, yMax, zMax, xMin, yMin, zMin;

                    //these along with the cornerOrigin define the four main corners 
                    bool Success = false;
                    for (int I=0; I<=1; I++){
                        for (int J=1; J<=399; J++){
                            scanTarget.Y = J*(int)(Math.Pow(-1.0,I));//Changes the direction searched if I=0 then J>0, if I=1 then J<0
                            if (Occupied(scanTarget)){
                                Success = true;
                                y=scanTarget.Y;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(Success){break;}
                    }
                    scanTarget.assign(cornerOrigin);
                    if(Success){
                        Success = false;
                        for (int I=0; I<=1; I++){
                            for (int J=1; J<=399; J++){
                                scanTarget.X = J*(int)(Math.Pow(-1.0,I));
                                if (Occupied(scanTarget)){
                                    Success = true;
                                    x=scanTarget.X;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(Success){break;}
                        } 
                    }
                    scanTarget.assign(cornerOrigin);
                    if(Success){
                        Success = false;
                        for (int I=0; I<=1; I++){
                            for (int J=1; J<=399; J++){
                                scanTarget.Z = J*(int)(Math.Pow(-1.0,I));
                                if (Occupied(scanTarget)){
                                    Success = true;
                                    z=scanTarget.Z;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(Success){break;}
                        }
                    }

                    //the following are/can be inffered based on where other corners are
                    xy.assign(x,y,cornerOrigin.Z);
                    yz.assign(cornerOrigin.X,y,z);
                    xz.assign(x,cornerOrigin.Y,z);
                    xyz.assign(x,y,z);

                    if (Success){//if any of the following are true then the object fails to be defined
                        if(!Occupied(xy)){Success = false;}
                        if(!Occupied(yz)){Success = false;}
                        if(!Occupied(xz)){Success = false;}
                        if(!Occupied(xyz)){Success = false;}
                    }


                    if (Success) {
                        xMax = (x>cornerOrigin.X) ? x : cornerOrigin.X;
                        xMin = (x<cornerOrigin.X) ? x : cornerOrigin.X;

                        yMax = (y>cornerOrigin.Y) ? y : cornerOrigin.Y;
                        yMin = (y<cornerOrigin.Y) ? y : cornerOrigin.Y;

                        zMax = (z>cornerOrigin.Z) ? z : cornerOrigin.Z;
                        zMin = (z<cornerOrigin.Z) ? z : cornerOrigin.Z;

                        return new box(new possition (xMin,yMin,zMin),new possition (xMax,yMax,zMax), true);
                    }
                            else {return new box(new possition (0,0,0),new possition (0,0,0), false);}
                }




        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            box Boxxy = new box();
            Boxxy = getBoundingBox(new possition (0,0,0));
            if (Boxxy.NotNull) {Console.WriteLine("Success");}
            else {Console.WriteLine("Failure");}
        }
    }
}
```

Assume the function `Occupied` requires one operation.  Does anyone know of a way I could optimize this further?

Edit: Someone had suggested I use an octree. I don't really know what that is and, after perusing wiki to find out what it is, I'm not sure how I would implement it or apply one to this problem.

Edit2:  I rewrote the code with a skeleton implementation so it can be compiled, it's meant as a mod for the game space engineers.  I had to write it in an online compiler so please excuse idiosyncrasy that emerge as a result.  The portion of this code I'm really asking about is the 'getBoundingBox' function.

Comment: Could you post the complete code? What is `scanTarget` or `Occupied`? How does this work? Why `399`? What does this formula do `float(J)*(pow(-1,I))`? What is `NULL`? It looks like pseudocode.

Comment: This does not compile `xy = {x,y,cornerOrigin.Z};`

Comment: This is missing parentheses `if (!Occupied(xy){ Success = false; }` and does not compile either.

Comment: You have 3 instances where Success == false is missing the ending semi-colon.

Comment: @t3chb0t I've edit the code to make it a bit clearer for you, and fixed the compilation errors you found, I had no access to a compiler when i wrote this and forgot NULL should be null in c#. 399 because that's the maximum distance the search should go to in any direction(400 units including the origin).

Comment: Your question is still quite chaotic. I can't tell what's the example and where the actual code begins that you'd like to have reviewed.

Comment: I don't know how I could make it more clear than "The portion of this code I'm really asking about is the 'getBoundingBox' function." If you have a suggestion for what would make this more clear for you I'd be happy to make some edits, but since I'm not sure what has you confused I don't really know how I could clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would clean your code before trying to make any performance changes to the algorithm.

### `struct possition`

You can find lots of articles and [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751911/why-are-c-sharp-structs-immutable) online that suggest to make structs immutable. This means we should remove method `assign` and make the properties readonly. Let's also rename this struct to `Position` while we're at it and make sure to use [C# Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) instead of those of Java.

```
public struct Position 
{
    public float X { get; }
    public float Y { get; }
    public float Z { get; }

    public Position (Position other) => this(other.X, other.Y, other.Z);

    public Position (float x, float y, float z) => (X, Y, Z) = (x, y, z);
}
```

The equality check could be simplified:

> ```
> public static bool operator ==(possition Pos1, possition Pos2){
>     if (Pos1.X == Pos2.X && Pos1.Y == Pos2.Y && Pos1.Z == Pos2.Z){
>             return true;
>     }
>     else {return false;}
> }
> ```

You don't need the explicit `if (condition) true else false` syntax.

```
public static bool operator == (Position source, Position target) 
        => source.X == target.X
        && source.Y == target.Y
        && source.Z == target.Z;
```

**Bug:** The inequality check is wrong. You should have used `!cond1 || !cond2 || !cond3` instead of `!cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3`.

> ```
> public static bool operator !=(possition Pos1, possition Pos2){
>     if (Pos1.X != Pos2.X && Pos1.Y != Pos2.Y && Pos1.Z != Pos2.Z){
>             return true;
>     }
>     else {return false;}
> }
> ```

But even better is to negate the equality check.

```
public static bool operator != (Position source, Position target) => !(source == target);
```

### `struct box`

I have no idea what `NotNull` means here. If you want the struct to be null-assignable, you should use a `Nullable<box>` instead. Also, `this.NotNull = NULL;` is a really unfortunate assignment. Why store the variable with its inverse meaning, it only adds confusion? `Min` and `Max` are common names for bounds, use them. Here's a refactored immutable struct.

```
public struct Box 
{
    public Position Min { get; }
    public Position Max { get; } 

    public Box (Position min, Position max) => (Min, Max) = (min, max);
}
```

### `public static box getBoundingBox`

- You state the helper `Occupied` used by `getBoundingBox` is for testing purposes only. Then why does `getBoundingBox` call it?
- There is no clear specification what this method should do. Start by providing a clear spec.
- You don't need the `#.f` semantics for providing floats to your classes. `cornerOrigin.assign(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);` can be written as `cornerOrigin.assign(0, 0, 0);`. - Since you no longer should assign, make a new instance instead `var corner = new Position(0, 0, 0);`. If you need to provided parameter to be able to store a different value, make it a by-ref parameter `getBoundingBox(ref Position cornerOrigin)`.
- You have recurring blocks of code `if(Success) Success = false;`. Rather than resetting variables, you should split this algorithm up into more and smaller methods instead.

---

☛ Once you have cleaned your code up, perhaps you could ask a follow-up question with code that's much more comprehensible.